# Отменить автоматическое добавление блока комментариев при создании класса

Tags: android-studio

Когда создаю новый класс, по умолчанию перед объявлением класса появляется блок комментариев

```
/**
* Created by ...
*/
```

Как сделать так, чтобы эти комментарии не добавлялись при создании класса?

Answer (score -1):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> -> `File and Code Templates`-> `Other`

Удалить `#parse("File Header.java")` в *.java